# Django - Update multiple objects at once

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have `Blank` model with foreign key `Branch`. When objects from `Blank` model created they have no `Branch`. In other window I have share button, by which I should assign `Branch` to these `Blank` objects in the given number range. For example, branches of blanks with number from 1 to 3 must be updated. But I don't know where and how should I realize update process. Here are my codes:

`views.py`:

```
def blanks(request):

    if request.method == 'POST' and 'create-blank' in request.POST:
        form = CreateBlankForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = CreateBlankForm()

    blank_list = Blank.objects.all().order_by('-created')

    # Realize pagination

    paginator = Paginator(blank_list, 5)
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

    try:
        blanks = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        blanks = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        blanks = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'blanks': blanks,
    }
    return render(request, 'blank.html', context)
```

`models.py`:

```
class Blank(models.Model):
    blank_series = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    blank_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    shared = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    number_from = models.IntegerField()
    number_to = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.blank_series
```

`forms.py`:

```
class CreateBlankForm(ModelForm):
    def save(self, commit=False):
        blank = super(CreateBlankForm, self).save(commit=False)
        number_of_objects = range(blank.number_from, blank.number_to+1)

        for i in number_of_objects:
            Blank.objects.create(
                blank_series = blank.blank_series,
                blank_number = i,
                shared = blank.shared,
                branch=blank.branch,

                number_from = blank.number_from,
                number_to = blank.number_to                
            )
```

`blanks.html`"

```
<form>
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <tr>
                            <th>{{ form.branch.label }}</th>
                            <td>{{ form.branch }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>{{ form.blank_type.label }}</th>
                            <td>{{ form.blank_type }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>{{ form.blank_series.label }}</th>
                            <td>{{ form.blank_series }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>{{ form.blank_number.label }}</th>
                            <td>
                                {{ form.number_from }}
                                {{ form.number_to }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="share-blank-btns">
                                <button class="share-blank-btn"><span class="material-icons">share</span><input type="submit" value="Share blanks" name="share-blank"></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either override the save() function of Blank model, or add a `signal` of `post_save` to adjust the Branches

OVERRIDE SAVE
models.py:

```
class Blank(models.Model):
    blank_series = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    blank_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    shared = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    number_from = models.IntegerField()
    number_to = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.blank_series
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # update the branches over here with the number_from & number_to range
        pass
```

POST_SAVE signal
Read how to do post_save signal here
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save

Comment: Thank you buddy, please if it is not hard for you, can you help me with scripts inside `save` method ?

Comment: You should include the Branch model and the actual logic you want to implement